# rails validation regular expression for www and http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

I want to validate a form input so that http:// and www is not allowed. Which REGEX would work?

For example:

**Allowed**

google.com

**NOT Allowed**

- www.google.com
- http://google.com
- http://www.google.com

**MODEL**

VALID_DOMAIN_REGEX = ???

validates :domain, format: { with: VALID_DOMAIN_REGEX }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `http://` contains so many forward slashes, this would be a good use for Ruby's %r{} regex literal syntax.

```
def has_forbidden_prefix?(string)
  string =~ %r{^(http://|www)}
end
```

This will return nil, falsy, if the string does not start with `http://` or `www`.

It will return 0, truthy (the offset of the first match) if the string does.

You can use `validate :some_method_name` to call a custom validation method in the model, I would structure it as follows

```
model MyThing
  validate :no_forbidden_prefix

  private

  def has_forbidden_prefix?(string)
    string =~ %r{^(http://|www)}
  end

  def no_forbidden_prefix
    if has_forbidden_prefix?(uri)
      errors.add :domain, 'The URI cannot start with "http://" or "www"'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. How can I include your solution in my model?

Comment: I have expanded my solution to give an example implementation, I find custom validations using private methods much more readable but this is just my opinion. :)

Comment: undefined local variable or method `uri'

Comment: I wasn't meaning that you should copy it verbatim ;) You want to supply the domain field that you are validating here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. So how can I finally validate the :domain column? Something like validates :domain, :no_forbidden_prefix? Or in the controller?

Comment: `validate :no_forbidden_prefix` at the top of my example will call the `no_forbidden_prefix` method every time the model is validated. In this method you add to `errors`, if your tests are failed, which will cause the model validation to fail.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how does the no_forbidden_prefix method knows which column to validate? How does the has_forbidden_prefix= method gets the uri?

Comment: pass the attribute you wish to validate to `has_forbidden_prefix?` in this case you probably want to validate `self.domain` so call `has_forbidden_prefix?(self.domain)` (or just `domain` since `self` is implicit in Ruby). `self.domain` should be set by your create action that uses params submitted by your form.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
/^[http\:\/\/|www].*/
```

For example:

```
1.9.2p320 :007 > "http://www.google.de".match /^[http\:\/\/|www].*/
 => #<MatchData "http://www.google.de">
1.9.2p320 :008 > "www.google.de".match /^[http\:\/\/|www].*/
 => #<MatchData "www.google.de">
1.9.2p320 :009 > "google.de".match /^[http\:\/\/|www].*/
 => nil
```

So it doenst match if its valid for your purposes...

Comment: `[http\:\/\/|www]` is a character class, maybe you intended to use grouping?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work when I do something like that: "www.google.com".sub(/^[http\:\/\/|www]./, "") => "w.google.com"

Comment: @toro2k yes I need to use grouping