# Validate that first char has to be integer or letter

Tags: ruby, regex, validation

I have this method where I "spot" user input I want to prevent.

```
def has_forbidden_prefix?(string)
  string =~ %r{^(http://|www.)}
end
```

If has_forbidden_prefix? is true than I don't want to accept the input.

For example:

Allowed: google.com

Not allowed: www.google.com, http://google.com, http://www.google.com

Now I want to detect also any beginning special characters in my method.

Not allowed: .google.com, /google.com, ...

What do I have to include in my regex?

Comment: I think you need to add some example strings, that you want to match. It's a bit unclear if you mean the first character of the string or the first character after www or http://.

Comment: Any string that matches your regex would already have the first character as a letter (supposing it is not multi-line).

Comment: thanks added some examples

Comment: `"google.com"` does not match your regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That regex matches what you **didn't** want from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967129/rails-validation-regular-expression-for-www-and-http)

So expanding you could have

```
def has_forbidden_prefix?(string)
  disallowed_string = string =~ %r{\A(http://|www)}
  non_alphanumeric = string =~ /\A[^a-zA-Z0-9]/

  disallowed_string || non_alphanumeric
end
```

Comment: I forgot the `begininning-of-string` specifier (`^`) in the second regex! Try again :)

Comment: Thanks again! :-) But shouldn't it be 0-9?

Comment: Looks like I need another coffee... Yes, it should!

Comment: That's kind of a lousy solution. You use 2 regexes to do the job of 1. Plus @sawa already pointed out that the distinction is meaningless.

Comment: Please read his previous question to understand what he is trying to achieve. This is for a validation. It makes much more sense to use different regexes to check different criteria over one regex as it is **much** more maintainable.

Comment: I don't understand why this has down-votes when it is exactly what is needed... Perhaps some people are misinterpreting the question.

Comment: Because the criteria are overlapping. If the first condition is true, the second is necessarily false. Therefore it might as well not be there.

Comment: I think you are confused and you think that it **should** start with 'http...' this is not the case.

Comment: `%r{^(http://|www)}` means it either starts with a `h` or a `w` (or is a multiline string)

Comment: Yes, but he is trying to look for strings that **DONT** start with (http://|www) **AND DON'T** start with an non-alphanumeric.

Comment: Therefore you can check if it **DOES** start with(http://|www) **OR DOES** start with a non-alphanumeric and **REJECT** it in this case. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws `"not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)"`

Comment: Look, if it starts with a `h` or a `w` it obviously starts with an alphanumeric. Can we at least agree on that? If so please delete this answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34545/discussion-between-aaron-cronin-and-pguardiario)

Comment: @pguardiario Can you provide a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

The regex to see if the first character is an alphanumeric or number is:

^[a-zA-Z0-9]

where ^ stands for the start of the string the regex pattern is applied to. For more info refer to http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it is absolutely correct! But I had a mistake in my initial question. I've updated it.